# ODataController converting json to array

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, odata

This is in continuation with one of the previous questions

I have a OData Controller with the Action as :

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("PostUpdate")]
public async Task<string> PostUpdate(HttpRequestMessage eventsToUpdate)
{

 //Do something
}
```

This is how I am calling the controller through the ajax call:

```
var eventsToUpdate = [];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  //Build the data
  var updatedT = {
   "Id" : (Id)?Id:0,
   "Desc" : CalculatedDesc
   }
   eventsToUpdate.push(updatedT);
}

Url = "Api/Odata/PostUpdate"

$.ajax({
url :Url,
type:"POST",
data:eventsToUpdate ,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(result) {

}
});
```

The problem is even after converting an array to json , the data is not available in the controller's action. This is what I did

```
var eventsToUpdate = JSON.stringify(eventsToUpdate);
```

But if I just pass

```
var updatedT = {
   "Id" : (Id)?Id:0,
   "Desc" : CalculatedDesc
   }
```

I get the same data in action . What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

What seems to me your `[HttpPost]` is expecting a key named `eventsToUpdate` but it doesn't find in the posted request as it is not there because of:

```
data:eventsToUpdate , // which is eq to = data:[{},{}...],
```

better to send an object like:

```
data:{eventsToUpdate:eventsToUpdate} ,
//----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------this key will be captured at backend
contentType:'application/json', //<------you would need to add this
```

and another suggestion is to use `traditional:true,` if required.

Also, `async Task<string>` if return type is string then you need to change the `dataType` of the ajax too or you should return json from the WebMethod.